# Run callbacks on locked iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

So basically I have a function which download all the content (videos) I use in my app. It's a asynchronus function and after I download a specific video, if it succeed I  just call it again and download the next one.

I'm using `AFNetwork` for my requests and I was struggling trying to figure out how to make my transfer work even when I had my Iphone locked, and I was finally able to figure it out using `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and setting `setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`.

But after my download is finished and it succeeded, if my Iphone is locked, the function is never called, only when I unlock it and open up my app again.

Is there any way to keep it running? Any solutions for that?

Answer (score 0):

may be it's because Background fetch is disabled.

Go to *Project setting -> Target -> Capabilities -> Background fetch*.

enable background fetch and check what happens.